# Grouping query into group and subgroup

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I want to group my data using SQL or R so that I can get top or bottom 10 `Subarea_codes` for each `Company` and `Area_code`. In essence: the `Subarea_codes` within the `Area_codes` where each `Company` has its largest or smallest result.

```
data.csv

Area_code  Subarea_code  Company   Result
10         101           A         15
10         101           P         10
10         101           C         4
10         102           A         10
10         102           P         8
10         102           C         5
11         111           A         15
11         111           P         20
11         111           C         5
11         112           A         10
11         112           P         5
11         112           C         10


result.csv should be like this

Company   Area_code  Largest_subarea_code  Result  Smallest_subarea_code    Result
A         10         101                   15      102                      10
P         10         101                   10      102                      8            
C         10         102                   5       101                      4
A         11         111                   15      112                      10
P         11         111                   20      112                      5
C         11         112                   10      111                      5
```

Within each `Area_code` there can be hundreds of `Subarea_codes` but I only want the top and bottom 10 for each Company.

Also this doesn't have to be resolved in one query, but can be divided into two queries, meaning smallest is presented in results_10_smallest and largest in result_10_largest. But I'm hoping I can accomplish this with one query for each result.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT Company, Area_code, Subarea_code MAX(Result) 
    AS Max_result
FROM data
GROUP BY Subarea_code
ORDER BY Company
;
```

This gives me all the `Companies` with the highest results within each Subarea_code. Which would mean: A, A, P, A-C for the data above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sqldf` package:

```
df <- read.table(text="Area_code  Subarea_code  Company   Result
10         101           A         15
10         101           P         10
10         101           C         4
10         102           A         10
10         102           P         8
10         102           C         5
11         111           A         15
11         111           P         20
11         111           C         5
11         112           A         10
11         112           P         5
11         112           C         10", header=TRUE)

library(sqldf)
mymax <- sqldf("select Company,
                  Area_code,
                  max(Subarea_code) Largest_subarea_code
                  from df
                  group by Company,Area_code")
mymaxres <- sqldf("select d.Company,
                          d.Area_code,
                          m.Largest_subarea_code,
                          d.Result
                  from df d, mymax m
                  where d.Company=m.Company and
                        d.Subarea_code=m.Largest_subarea_code")

mymin <- sqldf("select Company,
                  Area_code,
                  min(Subarea_code) Smallest_subarea_code
                  from df
                  group by Company,Area_code")
myminres <- sqldf("select d.Company,
                          d.Area_code,
                          m.Smallest_subarea_code,
                          d.Result
                  from df d, mymin m
                  where d.Company=m.Company and
                        d.Subarea_code=m.Smallest_subarea_code")
result <- sqldf("select a.*, b.Smallest_subarea_code,b.Result
                from mymaxres a, myminres b
                where a.Company=b.Company and 
                      a.Area_code=b.Area_code")
```

Comment: +1. I guess the expected result is slightly different than the `result`.  It could be a mistake from the OP.

Comment: Which mistake do you mean?

Comment: Didn't test it properly, this should be enough to start off, feel free to edit.

Comment: Yeah, the max/min query above is wrong as it should be `max(Result)´, `Subarea_code Largest_subarea_code´. But other than that it works!

Answer (score 5):

If you already doing it in R, why not use the much more efficient `data.table` instead of `sqldf` using SQL syntax? Assuming `data` is your data set, simply:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(Largest_subarea_code = Subarea_code[which.max(Result)],
            Resultmax = max(Result),
            Smallest_subarea_code = Subarea_code[which.min(Result)],
            Resultmin = min(Result)), by = list(Company, Area_code)]
#    Company Area_code Largest_subarea_code Resultmax Smallest_subarea_code Resultmin
# 1:       A        10                  101        15                   102        10
# 2:       P        10                  101        10                   102         8
# 3:       C        10                  102         5                   101         4
# 4:       A        11                  111        15                   112        10
# 5:       P        11                  111        20                   112         5
# 6:       C        11                  112        10                   111         5
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a discrepancy between the output shown and the description.  The description asks for the top 10 and bottom 10 results for each Area code/Company but the sample output shows only the top 1 and the bottom 1.  For example, for area code 10 and company A subarea 101 is top with a result of 15 and and subarea 102 is 2nd largest with a result of 10 so according to the description there should be two rows for that company/area code combination.  (If there were more data there would be up to 10 rows for that company/area code combination.)

We give two answers. The first assumes the top 10 and bottom 10 are wanted for each company and area code as in the question's description and the second assumes only the top and bottom for each company and area code as in the question's sample output.

**1) Top/Bottom 10**

Here we assume that the top 10 and bottom 10 results for each Company/Area code are wanted.  If its just the top and bottom one then see (2) later on (or replace 10 with 1 in the code here).  `Bottom10` is all rows for which there are 10 or fewer subareas for the same area code and company with equal or smaller results.  `Top10` is similar.

```
library(sqldf)

Bottom10 <- sqldf("select a.Company, 
                          a.Area_code, 
                          a.Subarea_code Bottom_Subarea, 
                          a.Result Bottom_Result,
                          count(*) Bottom_Rank
        from df a join df b  
        on a.Company = b.Company and 
           a.Area_code = B.Area_code and
           b.Result <= a.Result
        group by a.Company, a.Area_code, a.Subarea_code
        having count(*) <= 10")

Top10 <- sqldf("select a.Company, 
                       a.Area_code, 
                       a.Subarea_code Top_Subarea, 
                       a.Result Top_Result,
                       count(*) Top_Rank
        from df a join df b  
        on a.Company = b.Company and 
           a.Area_code = B.Area_code and 
           b.Result >= a.Result
        group by a.Company, a.Area_code, a.Subarea_code
        having count(*) <= 10")
```

The description indicated you wanted the top 10 OR the bottom 10 for each company/area code in which case just use one of the results above.  If you want to combine them we show a merge below.  We have added a Rank column to indicate the smallest/largest (Rank is 1), second smallest/largest (Rank is 2), etc.

```
sqldf("select t.Area_code, 
              t.Company, 
              t.Top_Rank Rank,
              t.Top_Subarea, 
              t.Top_Result,
              b.Bottom_Subarea,
              b.Bottom_Result
       from Bottom10 b join Top10 t
       on t.Area_code = b.Area_code and 
          t.Company = b.Company and
          t.Top_Rank = b.Bottom_Rank
       order by t.Area_code, t.Company, t.Top_Rank")
```

giving:

```
   Area_code Company Rank Top_Subarea Top_Result Bottom_Subarea Bottom_Result
1         10       A    1         101         15            102            10
2         10       A    2         102         10            101            15
3         10       C    1         102          5            101             4
4         10       C    2         101          4            102             5
5         10       P    1         101         10            102             8
6         10       P    2         102          8            101            10
7         11       A    1         111         15            112            10
8         11       A    2         112         10            111            15
9         11       C    1         112         10            111             5
10        11       C    2         111          5            112            10
11        11       P    1         111         20            112             5
12        11       P    2         112          5            111            20
```

Note that this format makes less sense if there are ties and, in fact, could generate more than 10 rows for a Company/Area code so you might just want to use the individual `Top10` and `Bottom10` in that case.  You could also consider jittering `df$Result` if this a problem:

```
df$Result <- jitter(df$Result)
# now perform SQL statements
```

**2) Top/Bottom Only**

Here we give only the top and bottom results and the corresponding subareas for each company/area code.  Note that this uses an extension to SQL supported by sqlite and the SQL code is substantially simpler:

```
Bottom1 <- sqldf("select Company, 
                          Area_code, 
                          Subarea_code Bottom_Subarea, 
                          min(Result) Bottom_Result
        from df
        group by Company, Area_code")

Top1 <- sqldf("select Company, 
                      Area_code, 
                      Subarea_code Top_Subarea, 
                      max(Result) Top_Result
        from df
        group by Company, Area_code")

sqldf("select a.Company, 
              a.Area_code, 
              Top_Subarea, 
              Top_Result,
              Bottom_Subarea
              Bottom_Result
        from Top1 a join Bottom1 b  
        on a.Company = b.Company and 
           a.Area_code = b.Area_code
        order by a.Area_code, a.Company")
```

This gives:

```
  Company Area_code Top_Subarea Top_Result Bottom_Result
1       A        10         101         15           102
2       C        10         102          5           101
3       P        10         101         10           102
4       A        11         111         15           112
5       C        11         112         10           111
6       P        11         111         20           112
```

**Update** Correction and added (2).

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are fine to fetch max result.

This solves the top10 issue:

```
data.top <- data[ave(-data$Result, data$Company, data$Area_code, FUN = rank) <= 10, ]
```

Comment: Probably `data[with(data, ave(-Result, Company, Area_code, FUN = rank)) <= 10, ]` will be better. Could do it similarly with `data.table`. Something like: `setDT(data)[, .SD[rank(-Result) <= 10], by = list(Company, Area_code)]`

Comment: How can I adjust this to bottom10?

Comment: Remove the `-` before `data$Result`?

Comment: Yeah... I thought I had a different result when I tried but it worked, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In this script the user declares the company. The script then indicates the max top 10 results (idem for min values).

```
Result=NULL
A <- read.table(/your-file.txt",header=T,sep="\t",na.string="NA")
Company<-A$Company=="A" #can be A, C, P or other values

Subarea<-unique(A$Subarea)

for (i in 1:length(unique(A$Subarea)))
{Result[i]<-max(A$Result[Company & A$Subarea_code==Subarea[i]])}
Res1<-t((rbind(Subarea,Result)))
Res2<-Res1[order(-Res1[,2]),]
Res2[1:10,]
```